# Calculator division using javascript

Tags: javascript

I wan't use division using javascript like calculator example if I make distributions 50000 / 0.5 = 100000(right) but in my script when I replace 0.5 to 0.6 then the result = 0.6(wrong) The javascript that I use

```
var nilai1 = 50000;
var nilai2 = 0.5;
var nilai3 = parseInt(nilai1)/(nilai2);
if(nilai3 %1 ==0){
$('‪#‎value‬').val(nilai3);
}
```

if I use the calculator then the result of the division of 50000 / 0.6 = 83333.33333333333

the question is how to make the distribution of such calculators?

thankyou

Comment: Why are you doing a `parseInt` on an integer value?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/xct03sas/3/)**

```
var nilai1 = 50000;
var nilai2 = 0.5;
var nilai3 = parseInt(nilai1)/parseFloat(nilai2);
if(nilai3 %1 ==0){
$('‪#‎value‬').val(nilai3);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `parseInt` and `parseFloat` ? Remove them and it will work as it is working right now..

Comment: parseInt and parseFloat here simply turn numbers into strings then straight back to numbers again. What's the point? An answer should say why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.